# Aurelia: Declaring custom element at top-level and access across application

Tags: aurelia, custom-element

I have a custom element called loading-bar which is used in a number of pages in my app. It's purpose is to show a status message while loading, download of content, and give response messages for backend actions.

loading-bar.html:

```
<template show.bind="visible">
    <i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin fa-fw" if.bind="type==1"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-check fa-fw" if.bind="type==2"></i>
    <span id="loading-text">${message}</span>
</template>
```

loading-bar.ts:

```
import { customElement, bindable, bindingMode, inject } from 'aurelia-framework';

@customElement('loading-bar')
export class LoadingBarCustomElement {
    private visible = false;
    @bindable({ defaultBindingMode: bindingMode.twoWay }) message;
    @bindable({ defaultBindingMode: bindingMode.twoWay }) type = 1;


    constructor() {
        this.visible = false;
    }

    messageChanged(newValue, oldValue) {
        if (newValue && newValue !== '')
            this.visible = true;
        else
            this.visible = false;
    }
}
```

At the moment all pages using the loading bar have this element declared in its html:

```
<loading-bar message.bind="loadMsg" type.bind="loadType"></loading-bar>
```

The loading-Bar is controlled by changing the loadMsg and loadType local variables in every page.

What I would like to do is to declare the loading-bar html at just on place, and be able (from any page) to call a method like "showBar(msg, type)" that will affect the globally declared loading-bar.

My first though is to declare the loading-bar in app.html, (just like my nav-bar is declared here) and inject a class (in all the pages' ViewModel), which contain the showBar(msg, type) method that will control the loading-bar.

I am not sure if this is the correct way forward, or how it's best implemented, and would appreciate some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `EventAggregator` to enable what you want to do.

**loading-bar.ts**

```
import { customElement, bindable, bindingMode, autoinject } from 'aurelia-framework';
import { EventAggregator, Subscription } from 'aurelia-event-aggregator';

@customElement('loading-bar')
@autoinject()
export class LoadingBarCustomElement {
    private visible = false;
    private sub1: Subscription;
    private sub2: Subscription;
    @bindable({ defaultBindingMode: bindingMode.twoWay }) message;
    @bindable({ defaultBindingMode: bindingMode.twoWay }) type = 1;


    constructor(private ea : EventAggregator ) {
        this.ea = ea;
        this.visible = false;
    }

    attached() {
      this.sub1 = this.ea.subscribe('show-loading', ({ message, type }) => {
        this.type = type;
        this.message = message;
      });

      this.sub2 = this.ea.subscribe('hide-loading', () => {
        this.message = '';
      });
    }

    detached() {
      this.sub1.dispose();
      this.sub2.dispose();
    }           

    messageChanged(newValue, oldValue) {
        if (newValue && newValue !== '')
            this.visible = true;
        else
            this.visible = false;
    }
}
```

and then publish the events elsewhere in your app like this:

```
import {autoinject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {EventAggregator} from 'aurelia-event-aggregator';

@autoinject()
export class ExamplePage {
    constructor(private ea: EventAggregator){
    ...
    }

    async methodUsingTheLoadingBar(){
        ...
        this.ea.publish( 'show-loading, { message: 'Loading...', type: 1 });
        const foo = await getData();
        ...
        ...
        this.ea.publish('hide-loading');
    }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant. Something like this I was looking for!

Answer (score -1):

Decided to solve it like this:

```
<loading-bar message.bind="lbc.loadMsg" type.bind="lbc.loadType"></loading-bar>
```

was added to app.html

Created a controller class which will be used as a singleton:

```
export class LoadingBarController {
    private loadMsg = '';
    private loadType = 1;

    public showBar(message, type) {
        this.loadType = type;
        this.loadMsg = message;
    }
    public hideBar() {
        this.loadMsg = '';
    }
}
```

This is injected in app.ts (with alias "lbc") where it actually is connected to the loading-bar element, as well injected in every viewModel of pages that wants to use the loading bar.
The loading-bar is then controlled through the injected controller like this:

```
@inject(LoadingBarController)
export class ExamplePage {
    constructor(private lbc: LoadingBarController){
    ...
    }

    methodUsingTheLoadingBar(){
        ...
        this.lbc.ShowBar('Loading...', 1);
        ...
        ...
        this.lbc.HideBar();
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use the EventAggregator to enable this. What you've created is a tightly coupled solution.